# error after xcode8 update "Use of instance member 'objects' on type Realm'

Tags: swift, realm

after xcode 8 update, after 'import Realm' etc, I am getting this error "Use of instance member 'objects' on type Realm - did you mean to use a value of type Realm instead?"

```
var specimens = try! Realm.objects(Specimen)
```

I have updated Realm in cocoapods. My view controller.swift also required some updates for xcode which might now be causing the error I presume. this is what I have, for setting up the Realm;

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

let realm = try! Realm()
var movies: Results<Specimen>?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.movies = self.realm.objects(Specimen)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the (missing) parentheses. You have:

```
var specimens = try! Realm.objects(Specimen)
```

You want something more like this:

```
var specimens = try! Realm().objects(Specimen)
```